# How do I ensure everything on my Facebook timeline is hidden to strangers?

Tags: facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy

When a stranger (i.e. person who is not my Facebook friend) opens my personal Facebook URL (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/myusername/), several posts on my timeline are displayed. How can I ensure that nothing is displayed on my timeline in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to those posts and change their visibility level. They're probably marked "public", which shows a globe icon. You need to click that and change the visibility to "Friends only" or whatever else is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Are you saying though that I need to set each post to 'Friends only' on a post-by-post basis, i.e. one at a time?  I'll of course do that if I have to, but it seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. A few years ago Facebook put something in place to change your Public posts to "Friends only" in bulk, because they changed the way a lot of things were being displayed. If it's still available, you should find it in your privacy settings where you can change your default post visibility.

Comment: Remember as well, going forward, that the visibility setting on a post is "sticky". If you post one thing as public, the next thing you post will default to public. You need to check the visibility is what you want before you post.

Comment: OK got it.  But the posts in-question are from 2013 and before.  When viewing my own timeline, is there a way to somehow jump to those posts?  Or do I have to manually scroll down through all of my recent posts, waiting for the page to reload older posts as it scrolls?  This seems like it will take quite a long time.

Comment: View your timeline as the public. (Or just view in an incognito tab.) That should let you easily find the posts with visibility to the public. And, yes, it may take a long time. Blame Facebook.

Comment: I have an alternate FB account that has no friends.  I can login to FB with that account and view the timeline of my main account.  That does indeed allow me to find the posts in-question.  But it doesn't allow me to edit the privacy of those posts.  I may create a separate question for this.  Incidentally, where do you typically go to ask similar Facebook how-to questions?  This Stack Exchange community?  Are there other forums I can try?  I tried the Facebook sub-Reddit a couple times, but didn't have much luck.